# ¿Cómo creo un middleware para impedir el acceso mediante url a vistas de mis siti utilizando entrust?

Tags: laravel

Estoy utilizando Entrust en Laravel v5.6.13, y necesito crear un middleware para restringir el acceso mediante url a los usuarios que no tengan el nivel de acceso o rol que les permita hacer esto, estube viendo algunos tutoriales pero cuando utilizo estos en lugar de redirigir al usuario de preferencia a una vista que tengo que pone acceso denegado. Ayuda por favor

Comment: por que no pones tu middleware para ver que podria estar pasando , quiza esta mal planteado.

Comment: Es que no tengo ningun middleware estoy utilizando una instruccin de Entrust mira te muestro una de las rutas en cuestión Route::get('AT2',['middleware'=>['role:admin'],'uses'=>'AT2Controller@index'])->name('AT2');

Comment: creo que estas usando mal ese entrust , no se pone ahi lo de middleware, se usa un route group

Comment: Lo vi en un tuto en GItHub pero si puedes decirme como uzarlo por favor

Comment: asi mira `Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@welcome');
  
});`

Comment: ese es el tuto que seguí pero tengo una duda, tengo que crear un grupo obligatoriamente porque yo no estoy trabajando con permisos sino solo con los roles directamente

Comment: mira esto entonces [middleware styde](https://styde.net/como-crear-y-usar-los-middleware-en-laravel-5-1/)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76646/discussion-between-luis-dariel-valenciano-and-sebastian-lagos-yanez).